# Python update value within function and reuse it

Tags: python, function

I searched a lot about this but I might be using the wrong terms, the answers I found are not very relevant or they are too advance for me.

So, I have a very simple program. I have a function that reads a web page, scans for href links using BeautifulSoup, takes one of the links it founds and follows it. The function takes the first link through user input.

Now I want this function to re-run automatically using the link it found, but I only manage to create endless loops by using the first variable it got. This is all done in a controlled environment which has a maximum depth of 10 links.

This is my code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
site=list()

def follinks(x):
    html = urllib.urlopen(x).read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = bs('a')
    for tag in tags:
        site.append(tag.get('href', None))
    x=site[2]
    print x
    return;
url1 = raw_input('Enter url:')
```

How do I make it use the x variable and go back to start and rerun the function until there are no more links to follow? I tried few variations of while true, but again ended in endless loops of the url the user gave.

thanks.

Comment: Do you want breadth-first (scan all links on one page, then go to the next pages) or depth-first (go down all 10 links, then go to the next page)?

Comment: I want to read all links in the page, then move to the 3rd, that's why I am putting them to a list, so I can pick the one I need. My problem is that I don't know how to loop it so it will do this:

Page1 -> Link3 -> Page2 -> Link3 -> Page3-> no more links.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called *recursion*. It's where you call a method from within its own body definition.

```
def follow_links(x):
    html = urllib.urlopen(x).read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # Put all the links on page x into the pagelinks list
    pagelinks = []
    tags = bs('a')
    for tag in tags:
        pagelinks.append(tag.get('href', None))

    # Track all links from this page in the master sites list
    site += pagelinks

    # Follow the third link, if there is one
    if len(pagelinks) > 2:
        follow_links(pagelinks[2])
```

Comment: Thank you, but using recursion I am entering again an endless loop, but this time I am repeating the second link I found.

Comment: If you want to limit the depth of recursion--how many times it calls, just implement a counter which you increment and halt at the desired depth.

Comment: I also tried using a while True in the start of the function but that didn't help much.

Comment: Sorry missed your comment Owen. I don't want to put a limit, I only want it to finish when it reaches a page when there are no more links.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I want to limit it to 10 times, would I create the counter inside the function?

Comment: It's looping infinitely because you had `x=site[2]` in there. Presumably you want some kind of logic or user action to decide what link to follow next? Just replace that line with the logic you need.

Comment: Though it is a good point about having a limit; if the next webpage links back to the first one, you could indeed enter a loop.

Comment: Thanks Riaz. What I am trying to achieve is for each link its visiting, scan the contents of the page, find all links, add them to a list, and follow the 3rd link in each iteration until there are no more links (or until the counter is finished), that's why the x=site[2] is there. Am I thinking this the wrong way?

Comment: See my edited answer. Using `site[2]` gives you the 3rd link you found _from the very start_. To follow the 3rd link in _each iteration_ you need to track those links in an intermediate variable.